# Gerrit Trigger executed without jenkins running

Tags: tomcat, jenkins, gerrit

I got an issue with Jenkins and gerrit. For some reason we had issues with receiving gerrit-trigger-mails twice ("Build Started") and there was also two jobs executed. One succeeded and one failed (due to concurrent execution issues). Also the build numbers are different. I receive one mail for the "new" build (e.g. 281) and one for an already existing one (e.g. 265). However, the results of the repeated "old" build are not updated on jenkins, so the duplicate job isn't writing anything.

However, I now tried to fix this and remove jenkins from tomcat. Result was, that I still got "Build Started" and "Build Failed" Mails with the link to the build on the shutdown jenkins (link returned http 404 ofcourse).

I then decided to complete wipe the tomcat (delete tomcat installation dir after uninstallation), restart the machine, install tomcat again and just start it (no jenkins added yet). Et voila, pushing to gerrit still got me new Started and Failed mails. My idea was, that maybe some other server is running with a tomcat and jenkins, but the "fail" mails I receive contain links to the exact machine I'm using, so I have no clue what happens, as they are auto generated and shouldn't contain "false" links.

Does anyone have any idea, what might cause this? I've reached the end of ideas on this, and have no idea what might cause this.

Thanks a lot,
Kay

Comment: How did you install jenkins? Did you install it using `apt-get install jenkins` or did you manually add it to tomcat?

Comment: Manually added it to tomcat (copied jenkins.war to webapps dir on tomcat) - the VM is a windows machine, so apt-get is no option

it worked like this for a long time without any issues, but for some reason at some point it started triggering twice

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ok, forget all I have written. Our infrastructure team is to blame.

We needed to clone this VM some weeks back. However, the "real" clone didn't do anything bad, as the jenkins was reconfigured on this machine. Nontheless, there was a second clone created, that wasn't listed anywhere and that noone knew about. This machine still had our jenkins running and kept listening to the gerrit triggers and happily commenting on them.

classical facepalm issue